# Talking about Past Tense

Tags: sentence-construction

I wanted to say that chocolate which I did not like to eat earlier when I was 5 year old I like to eat it now?
Then is it correct to say

"I did not like this chocolate earlier but now I like it very much"
Or
"I was not liking this chocolate earlier but now I like it very much"

Comment: *I did not like this chocolate when I was 5 but now I do.*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24974/sentence-construction-for-past

Comment: Another way to express this would be "I used to not like chocolate," which implies that you like it now.

Answer (score 1):

> I did not like this chocolate *when I was young*, but now I like it very much.

You can use *when I was young* to specify those things that change when you grow up. Of course if you want to be age specific, you could say *when I was five (years old)*.

Answer (score 0):

**You'd better use the past habit. The past habit is something you were doing it and you give up doing it. The action of doing something changes through time.**

---

Rule: 
Affirmative: Used to + Base verb (infinitive).
Negative: Didn't use to + inf.
Question: Did you use to + inf.
 You said, "I didn't like this chocolate, but now you did."

It would be better to use the rule, as follows:

> I didn't use to eat this chocolate, but now I like it very much.

Or,

> I didn't use to eat this chocolate, but now I do.

I hope this helps!